# Managing state with REST API for complex application

Tags: rest

I am developing a fairly complex web app with Angular2 front-end. I'd like to maintain all the client-server communication with Node.js-based RESTful API that passes JSON objects to and from.

However, I am somewhat confused about the requirement that REST should be stateless. There's quite a lot of data that is stored or generated at the server side, and storing it at client-side and attaching it to every request feels quite an overhead.

For example: there are hundreds of permissions associated with certain user (ie, what resource can be accessed at what level). Carrying those permissions by client non-encrypted is an obvious security issue; resubmitting all that data (encrypted) with every request feels weird. Refreshing them from database at every request would be performance hog.

I mean, of course at least some kind of access token, generated at the authentication, has to be passed to the server with every request. I just assumed I'd generate an non-guessable session id (at successful auth only), and pass it to the client in http-only (to restrict JavaScript access), secure (to enforce https-only) cookie and use this cookie to keep some frugal session state (like the permissions) at the server side. But it seems that this practice is frowned-upon in the REST world? is a stateful RESTful API is an oxymoron, a heresy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I am somewhat confused about the requirement that REST should be stateless

When in doubt, review the thesis -- in this case, Fielding is pretty clear about what *[stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)* means:

> Communication must be stateless in nature..., such that each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

In other words, no pronouns.  He describes the principal benefits when describing the [Client-Stateless-Server architecture](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm#sec_3_4_3)

> These constraints improve the properties of visibility, reliability, and scalability. Visibility is improved because a monitoring system does not have to look beyond a single request datum in order to determine the full nature of the request. Reliability is improved because it eases the task of recovering from partial failures. Scalability is improved because not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free resources and further simplifies implementation.
>
> The disadvantage of client-stateless-server is that it may decrease network performance by increasing the repetitive data (per-interaction overhead) sent in a series of requests, since that data cannot be left on the server in a shared context.

We're not assuming that the server is hosting pure functions; of *course* there is state on the server side.  In most cases, the point of having a REST api is to provide an interface that adapts the server side state (in whatever form) for the web.

> For example: there are hundreds of permissions associated with certain user (ie, what resource can be accessed at what level). Carrying those permissions by client non-encrypted is an obvious security issue; resubmitting all that data (encrypted) with every request feels weird. Refreshing them from database at every request would be performance hog.

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with the server caching some its own state, as an optimization to improve response time in the case of subsequent calls.  That's all work hidden behind the interface, and doesn't impact the REST constraints at all.  (If the next request is routed to another server, you'll get a cache miss and a second lookup, but those don't change the meaning of the request in any way.)

But the server should not be making any assumptions about the client state, because it can't see what's going on; the client state can change without the server being notified (back button, requests being handled by intermediary components, requests being managed by other copies of the same server).

The client, on the other hand, knows exactly what state the client is in when any given message is sent; it manages the session.  Any relevant session data gets copied into the request by the client, and the server acts on the request contents and its own state, without any memory of previous requests.